# Is it possible that some laptop models are not available to public?

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop

My company's ThinkPad `20FR-S11•••` (• = character is masked) manufactured 2017-03 is not available in any online catalog, nor on Lenovo [Product Specifications Reference](http://psref.lenovo.com/) page. The closest model number, which can be found, is `20FR`. See [search results for submodels of 20FR.](http://psref.lenovo.com/Search?k=20fr&c=false&s=false) Nothing there continues with `S` after `20FR`.

But as you can see, the above catalog site lists all published ten-characters-long model numbers with great detail for any Lenovo model. Just `20FR-S` series is not mentioned. Is it possible that it is a privately branded model made specially for large software company? (30,000+ employees.)

Has anyone else come across something like this?

**

**Update**: I can use [link](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-yoga-type-20fq-20fr/20fr/s11t0s?isdetect=true&linkTrack=Homepage:Body_DetectProduct) provided [by AFH](https://superuser.com/questions/1237958/is-it-possible-that-some-laptop-models-are-not-available-to-public?noredirect=1#comment1813326_1237958) to find S11 sub-model, but on the other hand, the `S11` part of the URL can be changed to anything (e.g. `ABCDEF`) and the page displays it as valid sub-model (e.g. `FR20ABCDEF`). What's going on that this sub-model number is not made public? **How can I learn about S11-specific features and price?**

Comment: "Is it possible that it is a privately branded model made specially for large software company?" - No, this isn't possible.

Comment: @Ramhound – please, how do you know? Could you elaborate more? If you add trustoworthy answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Is [This](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-X-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-X1-YOGA-TYPE-20FQ-20FR/20FR) the device?  Why did you mask the model number?

Comment: How do I know, I know because Lenovo, doesn't manufacture devices for companies.  30,000 unit order wouldn't justify the the one time manufacturing costs.  Lenovo does use unique model numbers for different regions so they can track sales.  We are talking hundreds of thousands of units in that case.

Comment: @Ramhound – question updated. Yes, it is that device. But that device has many listed sub-models varying in features and price. In my case it is unlisted sub-model (not model) with possible minor adjustments. Such a possible customization does not necessarily imply high manufacturing costs. The model number does *not* exist on google, but I have it here on several stickers. So if you only rely on google, there won't be any luck. I appreciate you are willing to help, but it is possible that you never seen thing like this. I wonder if there is someone who already seen it.

Comment: Yahoo! found [this reference](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-yoga-type-20fq-20fr/20fr/s11t0s?isdetect=true&linkTrack=Homepage:Body_DetectProduct) to an FR20S11 model.

Comment: @AFH – question updated

Comment: There is a slight difference, in that the `T0S` was appended, presumably by Lenovo. The same doesn't happen if you look for arbitrary strings, eg searching for `20FR-ABCDEF` finds [this variant](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-yoga-type-20fq-20fr/20fr/20frs1g100/warranty).

Comment: @AFH – thank you. The merit of the question is still interesting. How it is possible that these sub-models do not appear in catalogs or price lists?

Comment: Yes, it is interesting, but I don't think you'll get an answer unless you contact either Lenovo support or the purchasing department in your company.

Comment: @AFH – I agree. I just hoped that someone from advanced users visiting this site could have seen this in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Since asking the question, I see that my corporation regularly receives laptops with series not publicly advertised on the internet. (As checked via major search engines.)

The only way to learn about its specs and price is to check its specs in company's procurement platform while the model is available there.